# How do i match my Android Studio's ide template with Udacity's?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'm taking the udacity course on android development but i am using android studio 2.0, and so my ide's template doesn't match that of the videos? 
What do i do now?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, newcomers to a platform should not be using pre-release development tools for that platform. Hence, at minimum, you should switch to the current production release of Android Studio, which is 1.5.1 at the time of this writing.

The templates may still not match what is in the course, as I do not know if Google updates their course materials. Your options are:

1. Do not blindly follow their instructions, but instead determine yourself how to adapt what they suggest that you do to the templates that you are given.
2. See if there is a starter project that matches the training that you can import instead of using the new-project wizard and its templates (though this may not help with later new-activity wizards).
3. Switch to educational materials that are kept more up to date.
4. Figure out how to download whatever older version of Android Studio that they might have used in the course.

Comment: Whenever i reinstall a lower version it tells me my rendering library is higher than the current studio's own.

Comment: @MichaelSaneke: The drag-and-drop GUI builder in Android Studio is fairly unstable IMHO. I don't use it, and I teach people not to rely upon it. If you are using educational materials that rely upon the drag-and-drop GUI builder, I do not know what to tell you.